# Изменение контента в слайдере Views Sledeshow

Tags: drupal

Как можно изменить позиции и добавить другой контент в слайдере Views Sledeshow Drupal. Ни как не могу найти где можно изменить код.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Из скриншота видно, что добавить можно новый контент типа Слайдер, но отображается здесь только 5 последних, отсортированных по дате создания.